# Undefined columns selected when cleaning data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I am cleaning my data frame with 136 columns.
While doing so, I put the columns in the right order and removed some by making a subset of the data frame.

but then I try to run it I get an error:

*Error in `[.data.frame`(Stnd_valerie_dataset, (DFfinalAdult_22jan)) :
undefined columns selected*

I already checked the gramma of my new subset but can not find a mistake..

I hope someone can tell me how to fix this!

Comment: Please share a minimal reporducible example of your data along with the code you tried to run that gave the error. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: the code that i tried to run:
DFfinalAdult_22jan <- c("p_id", "sex", "age", "edu_level", "...continued with other variables and finally ended with )
then runned following code: 
 DFfinalAdult_22jan_VL <- Stnd_valerie_dataset[(DFfinalAdult_22jan)]

Comment: @deschen see comment above

Comment: Please could your edit your question to contain a reproducible example? The comment above doesn't give us enough information to reproduce your code. Please carefully read the link that @deschen shared

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't have the full dataframe to look at, it's going to be hard to give a full answer. That being said, running the subset function multiple times, each time adding a column, will tell you where your issue is.

```
foo <- df['a']
foo <- df['a','b']
```

Alternatively, you can do something similar, but with `select()` from `dplyr`:

```
foo <- df %>%
select('a','b')
```

You'll get an error message telling you which columns don't exist.

Comment: Thank you very much!! This worked finding the inconvenient